# Opinion surveys about specific tax rates

Tags: taxes, survey

I'm interested in data from public opinion surveys that have asked people about tax policy in terms of specific tax rates about specific levels of income (or other taxable quantities, like inheritance amounts).  That is, I want data from surveys that have asked questions like "Suppose a person earns $100,000 a year.  How much do you think that person should pay in income taxes?"  (Or, alternatively, "How much do you think that person should have left after paying income taxes?")  I'd be okay with multiple-choice answers if they were fairly granular (e.g., "less than $10,000", "$10,000-2000"), although I'd prefer data where respondents could give any number they liked.

There are three things I specifically want to avoid (and which are present in tax-policy survey data I've seen so far).  One is asking people only about their own situation (e.g., "How much tax do you think you should pay?").  Another is asking only about broad socioeconomic categories that are not defined by actual numbers (e.g., "How much should a lower-class family pay?").  The third is asking for opinions only in relative terms rather than in terms of actual numbers (e.g., "Do you think people earning more than $250,000 per year currently pay too much in income tax, about the right amount, or too little?").  That's why I'm interested in questions that use specific numbers for both the hypothetical income level and the hypothetical tax burden.

I'm looking for opinion surveys from the USA, although I'd also be interested in data from other countries for comparison, or in data from segments of the US population (e.g., individual states).

Comment: search [the gss codebook](http://gss.norc.org/documents/codebook/GSS_Codebook.pdf) and if that suffices, [analyze the microdata directly](http://www.asdfree.com/2012/10/analyze-general-social-survey-gss-with-r.html)

Comment: review http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/european%20social%20survey%20%28ess%29 and http://www.asdfree.com/2014/09/analyze-world-values-survey-wvs-with-r.html for european & worldwide opinion questions

Comment: All tax questions I can find in the GSS codebook suffer from one or more of the problems I mentioned in my question.

Comment: ess and wvs too?  search pew surveys maybe

Comment: I searched "tax" on ESS and also found only a few questions without numbers.  The WVS site doesn't seem to be working right; I can't access any of the documentation or data files.  I've looked at Pew in the past but found no questions with numbers.  This is why I asked this question.